# Dreamhost Ubuntu Errors installing Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, dreamhost

I have a dreamhost dedicated server and I'm getting a driver error when trying to use Postgresql. I followed the instructions [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216734878-PostgreSQL) to update/install pgsql. I got the error in the screenshot below.

The text of the error is:

`Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:`

`The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
postgresql : Depends: postgresql-9.1 but it is not going to be installed 
postgresql-contrib : Depends: postgresql-contrib-9.1 but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

[image]

If I run `psql --version` It says 9.1.23 is installed.

I'm not sure if everything is fine because of that or what. Also, the DB is on AWS and is version 10.5. Is that even going to be compatible?

The Ubuntu version on dreamhost is 12.04, which is no deprecated, so I doubt I'm going to be able to update the pgsql driver there. I don't have any experience with this stuff, and I've read some stuff, but don't want to just go running things as this is a production server that will be in use first thing Monday AM and I don't want to screw anything up.

Locally I'm using the pdo driver with pgsql.

Comment: Please post text, not images of text. I might have started testing the upgrade path sooner, though, if this is supposed to be live tomorrow AM.

Comment: nothing is going live tomorrow, i just don't want to screw with the server in a way that could impact things tomorrow. I can perform whatever updates need to be made later, i'm just trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: try running `apt update; apt dist-upgrade;`  before installing it, does that make a difference?